# fortrabbit - Problems pushing updates with git client

Tags: sftp, fortrabbit

Since I've upgraded my app from trial I can't no more update it with my git client. My SSH-key are ok, with other trial apps all works fine. 
In my app i get this error:

> A B O R T E D !! Could not get lock on repository; probably deployment
> in progress. Counting objects: 403, done. Delta compression using up 2
> threads.
>
> fatal:sha1 file '' write error: Invalid argument

Comment: downvote, as question better suited for personal support.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no answer for this question, as it is too specific for your App. It's not a good question for Stack Overflow. Please only ask questions here that are of general interest.